# Revolution slider not sliding on mobile - mobile touch swipe not working

Tags: wordpress, revolution-slider

I'm using revolution slider 5 and it's working perfectly on desktop but on mobile it just won't swipe slides by mobile touch. Slides are turning automatically but they won't slide on manual swipe. Do you have idea what is causing that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not working because most likely your slide's themselves are hyperlinked.

To solve this problem copy paste this code in custom javascript section in settings of your slider

```
(function() {

if(!('ontouchend' in document)) return;
var pageX, pageY, newX, newY, linked;

jQuery('.rev_slider').on('touchstart', function(event) {

    newX = newY = false;

    var target = jQuery(event.target),
    clas = target.attr('class');
    event = event.originalEvent;

    if(event.touches) event = event.touches[0];
    pageX = event.pageX;
    pageY = event.pageY;

    if(target.is('a') || target.closest('a').length) linked = target;

}).on('touchmove', function(event) {

    event = event.originalEvent;
    if(event.touches) event = event.touches[0];

    newX = event.pageX;
    newY = event.pageY;
    if(Math.abs(pageX - newX) > 10) event.preventDefault();

}).on('touchend', function(event) {

    if(newX !== false && Math.abs(pageX - newX) > 30) {

        eval('revapi' + jQuery(this).closest('.rev_slider_wrapper').attr('id').split('rev_slider_')[1].split('_')[0])[pageX > newX ? 'revnext' : 'revprev']();

    }
    else if((linked && newY === false) || (linked && Math.abs(pageY - newY) < 10)) {

        linked = linked.is('a') ? linked : linked.closest('a');
        if(linked.length) {

            if(linked.attr('target') === '_blank') {    
                window.open(linked.attr('href'));
            }
            else {
                window.location = linked.attr('href');
            }

        }

    }

    linked = newX = false;

});})();
```

This question is also well documented on Themepunch (author of the plugin) http://www.themepunch.com/faq/mobile-touch-swipe-slide-links-5-0/

Comment: I had a problem where slides with embedded Youtube videos weren't swipeable (ON the video - you could slide on the side of the videos) -- this script seems to have fixed that too.
Hope I'm not overlooking any implications this script might cause.

Answer (score 5):

[image: Slider Revolution Touch Settings]

As defined by the [developer's documentation](http://sttu.info/2hFlFeg), you can manually enable and disable vertical dragging in the slider's settings under the Navigation panel.